# How to produce a new data frame of mean monthly data, given a data frame consisting of daily data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a data frame containing the daily CO2 data since 2015, and I would like to produce the monthly mean data for each year, then put this into a new data frame. A sample of the data frame I'm using is shown below.

```
      month day cycle   trend
year                
2011    1   1   391.25  389.76
2011    1   2   391.29  389.77
2011    1   3   391.32  389.77
2011    1   4   391.36  389.78
2011    1   5   391.39  389.79
... ... ... ... ...
2021    3   13  416.15  414.37
2021    3   14  416.17  414.38
2021    3   15  416.18  414.39
2021    3   16  416.19  414.39
2021    3   17  416.21  414.40
```

I plan on using something like the code below to create the new monthly mean data frame, but the main problem I'm having is indicating the specific subset for each month of each year so that the mean can then be taken for this. If I could highlight all of the year "2015" for the month "1" and then average this etc. that might work?

Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated and if I need to make any edits please let me know, thanks so much!

```
dfs = list()
for l in L:
    dfs.append(refined_data[index = 2015, "month" = 1. day <=31].iloc[l].mean(axis=0))
mean_matrix = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).T
```

Comment: `year = 2015`
`month = 1`
`df = df.groupby(['year','month']).mean().loc[(year,month),['cycle','trend']]`

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe it's that simple, thank you so much for your comment, has been incredibly useful!